# facebook login not working after migrate site to new server

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

I recently migrated a website from one server to another.

The url is the same as I pointed the DNS to the new server.

However now I'm getting the following errors even though the setup is identical and the database is identical and I can't figure out how to solve it.

[image]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe Facebook checks IP addresses of domains, and has not updated some kind of cache yet? Try putting your site URL through the debug tool, to see what kind of content it receives.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was because I had to add the website url in the App Domains section so it would work for subdomains.